# Notation over Riemann Surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

It is known that a function f: $M \to N$, where M and N are Riemannian surface, is said to be holomorphic if $\psi^{-1}\cdot f \cdot \phi$ is holomorphic, with $\psi$ and $\phi$ as coordinate function respectively on $M$ and $N$. I found that the notation '$\psi^{-1}\cdot f \cdot \phi$' is the same of the equivalence: '$\psi=F(\phi)$' (without specifing what $F$ is). But, I don't understand why, and what is the meaning of this equivalence...

Comment: Is it holomorphic?

Comment: There is no "olomorphic."

Comment: Holomorphic, sorry (I'm from Italy...)